# Server Error in '/' Application. for iframe

Tags: html, url, iframe

I'm working on a html project. When I changed the url for the source, it could work locally.  But after I uploaded to our sever, it showed me the error below.

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /grouping/NoData

What I was seeing is that when I compiled the code, character '`&`' changed to '`&amp;`'. So I was thinking that is there any way that I could make '`&`' stay '`&`' in the Url? Or this is not the problem and someone may have better solution?

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML for the iframe element.

Comment: Please post your iframe's HTML to your question, not a comment reply. Also please explain how the iframe HTML is being rendered. Is it static HTML or generated on the server-side, or by client Javascript or something else?